# Directivity Integral of the form [sin(sin(x))/sin(x)]^2

Tags: integration, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

So I've been going through some material in acoustics and came across the this integral
$$
\int \left( \frac{\sin[\frac{1}{2} k L \sin\theta]}{\frac{1}{2} k L \sin\theta} \right)^2 d\Omega
$$

I've gone through two sources both that assert that doing the substitution $v=\frac{1}{2} k L \sin(\theta)$ gives you

$$
\frac{8\pi}{kL}\int_0^{kL/2} \left( \frac{\sin v}{v} \right)^2 dv
$$
I know that $d\Omega = \sin\theta \: d\theta d\phi$, giving me

$$
2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2} \left( \frac{\sin[\frac{1}{2} k L \sin\theta]}{\frac{1}{2} k L \sin\theta} \right)^2 \sin\theta d\theta
$$
From the substitution point, I have $dv = \frac{1}{2} k L \cos\theta d\theta$, therefore $d\theta = \frac{2 dv}{k L \cos \theta}$. The bounds I have are now $0$ and $kL/2$. After performing the substitution, I now have
$$
\frac{4\pi}{kL}\int_0^{kL/2} \left( \frac{\sin v}{v} \right)^2 \tan\theta dv= \frac{4\pi}{kL}\int_0^{kL/2} \left( \frac{\sin v}{v} \right)^2 \tan\left( \arcsin\left(\frac{2v}{kL}\right) \right) dv\\
= \frac{4\pi}{kL}\int_0^{kL/2} \left( \frac{\sin v}{v} \right)^2 \left( \frac{2v}{\sqrt{(kL)^2-4v^2}} \right) dv
$$

Clearly where I end up is not matching what is asserted to be true, unless I'm missing something that necessitates that $\frac{2v}{\sqrt{(kL)^2-4v^2}} = 1$.

EDIT:
$d\Omega = \sin \theta d\theta d\phi$

EDIT #2:
Fixed the upper bound on the second integration equation presented

Comment: What is $\Omega$? It appears to be the surface area, but is $\theta$ the distance from the equator or the pole? If it is the distance from the equator, then $\mathrm{d}\Omega=\cos(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi$. This would get the integral claimed.

Comment: Sorry, $d\Omega$ is the differential solid angle

Comment: Yes, I see that you stated that before, but is $\theta$ measured from the equator (like latitude) or from a pole?

Comment: $\theta$ is the zenith angle (pole to pole) and $\phi$ is the azimuth angle (equatorial trace)